# Файлы, почему нуль учитывается?

Tags: pascal

Почему 0 учитывается в итоговом файле и все числа соединены?

```
 var 
    g: file of integer; 
    c,max,min: integer; 
    imax,imin,n: integer;
    begin 
    //создание файла 
    assign(g,'file'); 
    rewrite(g); 
    writeln('Введите в файл целые числа, окончание ввода 0:'); 
    repeat 
    read(n); 
    if n<>0 then write(g,n); 
    until n=0; 
    writeln('Содержание исходного файла:'); 
    reset(g);
    while not (eof(g)) do 
    begin 
    inc(n); 
    read(g,c); 
    write(c); 
    if n=0 then 
    begin 
    max:=c; min:=c; imax:=0; imin:=0; 
    end else 
    begin 
    if c>max then 
    begin 
    max:=c;imax:=n; 
    end; 
    if c<min then 
    begin 
    min:=c;imin:=n; 
    end; 
    end; 
    end; 
    writeln; 
    seek(g,imax); 
    write(g,min); 
    reset(g); 
    seek(g,imin); 
    write(g,max); 
    writeln('Содержимое итогового файла в обратном порядке'); 
    while n>=0 do 
    begin 
    seek(g,n); 
    read(g,c); 
    write(c); 
    dec(n); 
    end; 
    close(g); 
    end.
```

Comment: Отформатируйте исходник, чтобы его можно было читать.

Answer (score 0):

Как может сработать `if n=0` после `inc(n);`? Последнее нужно перенести в конец цикла

`все числа соединены?` выводите их `writeln`, либо добавляйте пробел после числа при использовании `write`

`Почему 0 учитывается в итоговом файле` - потому что последний цикл работает `Len+1` раз, где Len  - длина файла